# How to properly deny Railo directory access through Apache

Tags: security, apache2, httpd.conf

I've been battle tested on this and failed to achieve my goal which is to deny all access to all directories except the Public directory and only allow access to all all other directories with specific IP addresses.

To get Railo+Apache+Tomcat installed I pretty much followed this script: https://github.com/talltroym/Railo-Ubuntu-Installer-Script then verified settings with this tutorial: http://blog.nictunney.com/2012/03/railo-tomcat-and-apache-on-amazon-ec2.html

From the installation script these mods are enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

Outside of the script I copied the sites-available to sites-enabled then reloaded Apache.

I have a directory created for Railo cmfl located at /var/www/Railo/  Navigating the browser to http ://Server_IP_Address/Railo forces ssl and relocates to https ://Server_IP_Address/Railo which shows off index.cfm.  Not providing index.cfm and omitting https indicates that the DirectoryIndex directive and RewriteCond of Apache appears to be working for the sites-enabled VirtualHost.

The problem I'm encountering is that I cannot seem to deny access to all directories except Public.  My directory structure is rather simple and looks like this:

> - Railo
>
>   - error
>   - Public
>   - NotPublic
>   - Sandbox

These are my sites-enabled configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    #Default Deny All to prevent walking backwards in file system
    Alias /Railo/ "/var/www/Railo/"
        <Directory ~ ".*/Railo/(?!Public).*">
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from All
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.cfml default.cfm default.cfml index.htm index.html index.cfc
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Alias /Railo/ "/var/www/Railo/"
    <Directory ~ "/var/www/Railo/(?!Public).*">
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from All
    </Directory>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

    #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
    #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
    #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
    #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
    #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   Access Control:
    #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
    #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
    #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
    #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
    #   for more details.
    #<Location />
    #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
    #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
    #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
    #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
    #</Location>

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #     into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o StrictRequire:
    #     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
    #     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
    #     and no other module can change it.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #     directives are used in per-directory context.
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
    #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
    #     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #     works correctly.
    #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.cfml default.cfm default.cfml index.htm index.html
    #Proxy .cfm and cfc requests to Railo
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
    #Deny access to admin except for local clients
    <Location /railo-context/admin/>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
#       Allow from <Omitted>
#       Allow from <Omitted>
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The apache2.conf includes the following:

```
 # Include the virtual host configurations:
    Include sites-enabled/



        <IfModule !mod_jk.c>
                LoadModule jk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_jk.so
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule mod_jk.c>
                JkMount /*.cfm ajp13
                JkMount /*.cfc ajp13
                JkMount /*.do ajp13
                JkMount /*.jsp ajp13
                JkMount /*.cfchart ajp13
                JkMount /*.cfm/* ajp13
                JkMount /*.cfml/* ajp13
                # Flex Gateway Mappings
                # JkMount /flex2gateway/* ajp13
                # JkMount /flashservices/gateway/* ajp13
                # JkMount /messagebroker/* ajp13
                JkMountCopy all
                JkLogFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
            </IfModule>
```

I believe I understand most of this except the jk_module inclusion which I've noticed has an error that shows up in the logs that I can't sort out:

> [warn] No JkShmFile defined in httpd.conf. Using default
>   /etc/apache2/logs/jk-runtime-status

I've checked my Regular expression against the paths of the directories with RegexBuddy just to be sure that I wasn't correct.  The problem doesn't appear to be Regex related although I may have something incorrect in the Directory directive.  The Location directive seems to be working correctly for blocking out Railo admin site access.

Comment: I'm terrible with clarity.  I guess what I'm trying to sort out is why the Directory directive, <Directory ~ ".*/Railo/(?!Public).*">, fails, but the Location directive, <Location /railo-context/admin/>, works.  If I substitute <Directory ~ ".*/Railo/(?!Public).*"> with <Location ~ ".*/Railo/(?!Public).*"> I get the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a complaint from the mod_jk connector wanting a file that it can use for shared memory purposes. The most common reason to actually *need* this file is for load balancing, which it doesn't look like you're doing. The other reason is for status workers, which are rarely, if ever used.

You can address the error, if you like, with a line similar to the following in your apache config:
JkShmFile /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.shm

However, it will not hurt you to simply ignore the error.

There is a detailed description of what the jkshmfile is for here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll see if I can silence the JkShmFile error with that info.